# Javascript returning weird values

Tags: javascript

I find myself needing to do some work with pretty small decimals, formatted a particular way, and javascript is doing weird things to them that I don't understand.

Each number enters the function formatted like this: `0.0000000000`. That's ten decimal places. Most of the time, that will mean trailing zeros, like this: `0.0011000000`.

Now, I wouldn't think this would matter, because before doing any other work with them, I turn them into integers, through the simple expedience of multiplying them by exactly 10000000000.

But when I do that, I sometimes get results that look like this:

```
var bigNum = 0.0000050000 * 10000000000; //Returns a value of 50000.00000000001
```

What the heck is going on here? Where is that extra 1 at the end coming from?

Comment: Basic principle of how floats work.

Comment: If you know the exact number of decimals, consider having your number as a string: `var bigNum = parseInt("0.0000050000".replace(".",""),10);`

Comment: You might want to look into many of the big number libraries out there for javascript (depending on your needs), as javascript does use floating point numbers.

Comment: I feel dumb now. For some damn fool reason, I'd forgotten about the floats. Duuuuurrr... Using toString() should do the trick. And now I'm going to spend a little time kicking myself.